# How to stop transaction in SQL stored procedure when pop up alert message

Tags: c#, javascript, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Based on below C# code i have wrote the statement  in SQL stored procedure when inv_qty == 2 , to pop up alert message.

But after showing the alert message.The data transaction has been recorded.How to stop the transaction if pop up the alert message is active?

As i know SQL stored procedure is not able to stop the transaction if write the statement, How can i achieve this?

```
 float INV_QTY = Convert.ToInt32(_cmd.Parameters["@RecordFound"].Value.ToString());
                   if (INV_QTY == 2)
                 {
         ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Message", "alert('" + Item + " Qty is more than exist Qty');window.location.href = 'MMS_Issue.aspx';", true);
                    }
    USE [CIMProRPT01]
     GO
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
     GO
   SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
       GO
     ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[MMSIssue_InsertOrUpdate] 
     @INV_TRANS_ID VARCHAR(40)
     ,@INV_ID VARCHAR(40)
      ,@INV_LOCATION VARCHAR(40) 
      ,@INV_QTY FLOAT
      ,@INV_TRANS_REQUESTOR VARCHAR(40)
      ,@INV_TRANS_REFNO VARCHAR(40)
      ,@INV_TRANS_REMARK VARCHAR(255)
      ,@INV_REASON_ID VARCHAR(40)
     ,@INV_REASON_REMARK VARCHAR(255)
      ,@INV_CREATE_DATE DATETIME
       ,@INV_CREATE_USER VARCHAR (255)

       ,@INV_FROMLOC VARCHAR (40)
        ,@RecordFound INT OUTPUT
      AS
         BEGIN
      SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM OTH_INV_QTY_LOC WHERE INV_ID = @INV_ID and INV_LOCATION = @INV_LOCATION)
BEGIN
    UPDATE OTH_INV_QTY_LOC SET [INV_ID] = @INV_ID,INV_LOCATION = @INV_LOCATION , INV_QTY = INV_QTY - @INV_QTY WHERE INV_ID = @INV_ID AND INV_LOCATION = @INV_LOCATION

    INSERT INTO OTH_INV_TRANSACTION (INV_TRANS_ID,INV_ID,INV_TRANS_LOCATION,INV_TRANS_QTY,INV_TRANS_REQUESTOR,INV_TRANS_REFNO,INV_TRANS_REMARK,INV_REASON_ID,INV_REASON_REMARK,INV_CREATE_DATE,INV_CREATE_USER,INV_FROMLOC)VALUES (@INV_TRANS_ID,@INV_ID,@INV_LOCATION,@INV_QTY,@INV_TRANS_REQUESTOR,@INV_TRANS_REFNO,@INV_TRANS_REMARK,@INV_REASON_ID,@INV_REASON_REMARK,@INV_CREATE_DATE,@INV_CREATE_USER,@INV_FROMLOC)


    DECLARE  @InvFindQTY FLOAT SET @InvFindQTY = ( SELECT INV_QTY FROM OTH_INV_QTY_LOC)

    IF  @InvFindQTY >= @INV_QTY 
    BEGIN
        SELECT @RecordFound = 2
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT @RecordFound = 1
    END
END
      ELSE 
      BEGIN
           SELECT @RecordFound = 0
   END
         END
```

Comment: `BEGIN TRY`/`END TRY`/`BEGIN CATCH`/`END CATCH`.

Comment: You have to split you procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote `when inv_qty == 2` but your procedure returns `@RecordFound` and based on my understanding of the sql everything is fine if `@InvFindQTY >= @INV_QTY` and the proc returns `@RecordFound = 2`

- The value `@INV_QTY` is passed to the procedure
- the column `inv_qty` of the table `oth_inv_qty_loc` is updated `inv_qty = inv_qty - @INV_QTY` if the condition `inv_id = @INV_ID AND inv_location = @INV_LOCATION` is given
- the value of `@InvFindQTY = (SELECT inv_qty FROM   oth_inv_qty_loc)` is retrieved after the update
- and `@RecordFound` is set depending on `@InvFindQTY >= @INV_QTY`

So basically it seems that you can wrap the statement in a transaction and update the table only if `inv_qty >= @INV_QTY`  which means if the current stock is greater or equal the amount `@INV_QTY` which someone wants to take out of the stock.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot pause initiated transaction, you need to split up your procedure into two parts and call the second after your popup or whatever condition you feel like.

If you want to rollback transaction you an use BEGIN TRAN and COMMIT/ROLLBACK respectively. .NET [Transactions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqltransaction%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) can also be used for rollback.

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[MMSIssue_InsertOrUpdate]
    @INV_TRANS_ID VARCHAR(40)
    ,@INV_ID VARCHAR(40)
    ,@INV_LOCATION VARCHAR(40) 
    ,@INV_QTY FLOAT
    ,@INV_TRANS_REQUESTOR VARCHAR(40)
    ,@INV_TRANS_REFNO VARCHAR(40)
    ,@INV_TRANS_REMARK VARCHAR(255)
    ,@INV_REASON_ID VARCHAR(40)
    ,@INV_REASON_REMARK VARCHAR(255)
    ,@INV_CREATE_DATE DATETIME
    ,@INV_CREATE_USER VARCHAR (255)
    ,@INV_FROMLOC VARCHAR (40)
    ,@RecordFound INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF EXISTS(SELECT * 
        FROM OTH_INV_QTY_LOC 
        WHERE INV_ID = @INV_ID 
            AND INV_LOCATION = @INV_LOCATION)
    BEGIN
        BEGIN TRY   
            -- start the transaction
            BEGIN TRANSACTION 

            UPDATE OTH_INV_QTY_LOC 
            SET [INV_ID] = @INV_ID,INV_LOCATION = @INV_LOCATION , INV_QTY = INV_QTY - @INV_QTY 
            WHERE INV_ID = @INV_ID AND INV_LOCATION = @INV_LOCATION

            -- you can start the transaction from here
            -- BEGIN TRANSACTION 

            INSERT INTO OTH_INV_TRANSACTION (INV_TRANS_ID,INV_ID,INV_TRANS_LOCATION,INV_TRANS_QTY,INV_TRANS_REQUESTOR,INV_TRANS_REFNO,INV_TRANS_REMARK,INV_REASON_ID,INV_REASON_REMARK,INV_CREATE_DATE,INV_CREATE_USER,INV_FROMLOC)
            VALUES (@INV_TRANS_ID,@INV_ID,@INV_LOCATION,@INV_QTY,@INV_TRANS_REQUESTOR,@INV_TRANS_REFNO,@INV_TRANS_REMARK,@INV_REASON_ID,@INV_REASON_REMARK,@INV_CREATE_DATE,@INV_CREATE_USER,@INV_FROMLOC)

            DECLARE  @InvFindQTY FLOAT 
            SET @InvFindQTY = ( SELECT INV_QTY FROM OTH_INV_QTY_LOC)

            IF  @InvFindQTY >= @INV_QTY 
            BEGIN
                SELECT @RecordFound = 2;
                THROW 51000, '@RecordFound = 2', 1; 
            END
            ELSE
            BEGIN
                SELECT @RecordFound = 1
            END
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH         
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION            
        END CATCH

        -- Commit the transaction 
        IF XACT_STATE() = 1 COMMIT TRANSACTION 
        -- For safety
        ELSE IF XACT_STATE() = -1 ROLLBACK TRANSACTION 
    END
    ELSE 
    BEGIN
        SELECT @RecordFound = 0
    END
END
```